# Ispell + Hunspell recognizes everything after the apostrophe a different word

Tags: flyspell, ispell, hunspell

I'm using `flyspell-mode` with `ispell` and `hunspell` - as the dictionary backend, the problem is: if I type a word, for example `you've` or `you're` it recognizes `ve` and `re` as individual words. I want to fix that so it recognizes apostrophes as part of words.

Answer (score 3):

This can stem from using Unicode apostrophes (U+2019, `’`) instead of ASCII single quotes (`'`), which certain Emacs major/minor modes might substitute automatically.

Have a look at http://www.pertinentdetail.org/IspellCharacterMapsError for one user's detailed solution to this problem using `hunspell`.  The gist is that both Emacs and the dictionary back end need to be told what extra characters can count as parts of words.  I use `aspell`, which already handles U+2019, so I just have to tell Emacs to accept the character by adding

```
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '((nil "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "['’]" t nil nil utf-8))))
```

to my `.emacs` configuration file.  Depending on which dictionary you use, the above arguments may need to be adjusted; see the [documentation](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/b77f6af24e9193a4f70622cda6d641c58e885c22/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el#L550) for `ispell-dictionary-alist` for their explanation.